# SQL. Re: inner joins & foreign keys

Tags: asp.net, sql, join, inner-join, acid

Good day.

I have a basic question on SQL and table structure.

What we have now: 17 tables. These tables include 1 admin table. The other 13 tables are all branched off 3 "main" tables: customers, CareWorkers, Staff.

If I'm wanting to adhere to ACID ideology, I want to then create tables that each houses unique information.

My question is, and what I'm trying to wrap my head around, when I create each of these "nested-deeper" (not sure what to call it) tables, I simply do an inner join statement to grab the foreign key on my ASP.NET app correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, inner join is how you get your tables "back together", and @SpectralGhost's example is how you do it. But you might want to consider doing it in the database rather than in your ASP code. The way you do that is with views. If you create a view (the syntax is CREATE VIEW and there are plenty of examples out there) then you can make the database schema as complex as you need to without making it hard to use in your ASP application. You can even make views updatable (you define an "INSTEAD OF" trigger, again, many examples if you search).

But you probably don't want to update a view, or a table, directly from your ASP code. You probably want to define STORED PROCEDUREs that update your data, and call those from your ASP code. This allows you to restrict access to your tables and views to read only and force any writes to come through a stored procedure you can control better. This prevents SQL INJECTION, making your ASP application much more secure. If the service account the application pool you ASP page runs under can pass raw queries to the database then any compromise can do tremendous damage to your database. If all it can do is execute a stored procedure where the parameters can be changed but not the functionality, they can only put some junk values in, or maybe not even that if you range check well.

The last bit of advice is that you are not preserving "ACID", you are preserving "NORMALIZED". It's definitely a tough concept to wrap your head around, here's a resource that helped me out a great deal when I was starting out. http://www.marcrettig.com/data-normalization-poster/ I still have a copy on my wall. You shouldn't obsess over normalization, but you should definitely keep it in mind and stick to it when you reasonably can. Again, there are numerous resources a search will get you, but the basic benefit is a normalized database is much more resistant to consistency problems, and is more storage efficient. And since disk IO is slow, storage efficient is usually query efficient too.

Comment: Appreciate it. I understand a bit better now.

Answer (score 0):

They are related tables. You should have at least one table with a primary key and often several that related back to that table from that table's foreign key.

```
TableOne
  TableOneID

TableTwo
  TableTwoID
  TableOneID
```

TableTwo relates to TableOne via TableOneID. An inner join would give you where there are records in both tables based on your join. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableOne t1
INNER JOIN TableTwo t2 ON t1.TableOneID=t2.TableOneID
```

Specifically how to do this in your application depends on your design. If you are using an ORM, then actual SQL is not terribly important. If you are using stored procedures, then it is.